# Running source command with -x for debugging

Tags: shell, dash

I am trying to understand how a shell script is working. The tutorial states that the script should be run as the following way:

```
source oe-init-build-env rpi-build
```

Usually when doing this kind of research I would do `sh -x oe-init-build-env rpi-build`. However this approach wouldn't be the optimal one here because it would run the script in a new shell.

Is there a way to run a script with source and pass it the `sh` flags?

Answer (score 9):

Just add a `set -x` in the script you are sourcing. You can end that by adding `set +x` in the script, to e.g. limit the output of your debug work.

Answer (score 2):

```
source <(echo "set -x"; echo "set -- rpi-build"; cat oe-init-build-env; echo "set +x")
```